# What is your workflow to create assignments using jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am teaching a python course. I use Jupyter notebooks to prepare class notes. I also use Jupyter notebooks to prepare questions for assignments - I use notebooks to prepare the questions and solve them. Then I copy paste the questions (without solution) before sending to the students.

I was wondering whether there is a more streamlined workflow. Is there a way hiding the solution from the students in a notebook? If so, I could push the notebook to github and the students would be able to see the questions only.

Comment: I think this could be a good question if you elaborate more, or else it boarders on being too broad. So, for example, do you typically write stubs of functions that your students are expected to fill out? But when you write the question, you fill in the stub? Or maybe, you have a jupyter cell with the question, and an empty cell for the answer, but you fill out that cell while you are producing the answers, and then have to manually copy-and-paste? If so, you may be able to automate that last part.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think an example would be most informative. What I am trying to do is ask questions such as: Read datafile XYZ and plot variable as a function of variable b. Then I expect students to write the code that does that. I typically try out the exercise before sending it on to the student to get a feeling of the difficulty and whether the output is interesting/relevant. So, what I want is a workflow that allows me to come up with a question, solve it and only pass the question on to the students.